# Can't stackalloc be used in C# to initialize a previously declared pointer?

Tags: c#, stackalloc

I just discovered the `stackalloc` notation of C# has an unbelievable quirk, please see the following code:

```
//          int *p;
//          p = stackalloc int[42];  // won't work! 
//  Error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `stackalloc' (CS1525) 

            int *p = stackalloc int[42]; //works
```

My intention is to use stackalloc in a ternary expression like this:

```
int *p = size > 0xFFFFF ? (int*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size).ToPointer() : stackalloc int[size];
```

The totally unexpected strike of compiler shocked me hard. I'd really appreciate if someone could shed some light on this strange behavior. I've tested it on both mono and .net, neither works.

Comment: It would help if you explained what you expected to happen and what actually happens. And why you are even using unsafe code in C# to begin with.

Comment: Error message added. As for the unsafe code, I sure have my use case, it has nothing to do with my question, why should I explain that to you?

Comment: I thought you were looking for help. When something out of the norm is being used, explaining the reason for it can help with finding suitable solution. Do as you please.

Comment: I edited the title to make it more relevant to the question.

Answer (score 9):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4(v=vs.100).aspx

You can use stackalloc only when declaring and initializing a local variable.

Answer (score 5):

People have already answered this, that you can only use it when declaring and initialising a local variable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4(v=vs.110).aspx.

However, if you're wondering what the reason for this is, it's lexical scoping.  A local variable declaration creates a lexical scope containing one or more basic blocks.  The CLR requires that the stack pointer is at the same position at the beginning and end of each such basic block.  Control transfer statements can only jump to the first instruction of a basic block.

When you use `stackalloc`, then the compiler needs to make some room on the stack by decrementing the stack pointer and incrementing it again when the allocated variable goes out of scope.

If you're inside an expression evaluation, there will be temporary values on the stack, so where should the compiler put that variable?  Allocating it at the beginning of the method is not an option because you can use an expression to specifiy the size.

Therefor, you have to explicitly tell the compiler where you want that variable to be allocated and for how long the memory should be kept.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, seems justified, but still, we may do the same thing in C `int *a = n > 42 ? (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n) :(int*)alloca(sizeof(int)*n);` and gcc doesn't complain. So I think to make it work only need a little bit trick that any compiler can play.

Comment: No little trick would help you because this would break a fundamental design concept if the .NET CLR: verifiability.  In your example, the stack pointer would have a different value after that instruction.  This is not allowed.  The stack pointer must have the same value at the beginning and end of each basic block.

Comment: @baulig But I certainly can do this: `int *pOuter;{int *pInner = stackalloc int[1];*pInner = 42;pOuter = pInner;}Console.WriteLine(*pOuter);` from a programmer's point of view, the only thing that matters is the address, not the variables.

Comment: Martin, you're confusing the IL operand stack (which is a virtual stack used for verification purposes - it does actually correspond to anything physical when the program is running) with executing stack which `stackalloc` allocates from.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that C++/CLI also allows to use `alloca()` in pure managed code (i.e. when compiling with /clr:pure), which of course compiles to the same exact IL as C# `stackalloc`, but without any of its restrictions. So this is purely a C# restriction, not a CLR restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Understandable it is a quirky behavior...and I do not have the answers as to why, but it is documented on MSDN

see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx